# Programmatically sending an app to background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to send the application to background? Similarly to how you can call `XCUIApplication.terminate()`, I have some UI Elements to test on `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)`. Does anyone know if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend checking out `XCUIDevice`. Here is how you might press the home button and then relaunch the application

```
func testExample() {

    // Has a nav bar.
    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().navigationBars.element.exists)

    XCUIDevice().press(XCUIDeviceButton.home)
    // Before Swift 3: XCUIDevice().pressButton(XCUIDeviceButton.Home)
    XCUIApplication().launch()

    // Navigationbar still there on second launch.
    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().navigationBars.element.exists)
}
```

Comment: Works well with iOS Simulator (9.3) and Xcode 7.3. Thanks!

Comment: According to the API documentation of [`XCUIApplication.launch()`](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUIApplication.html#//api/name/launch) (Xcode 7.3.1), it TERMINATE the application if it is already running. I think it is not suitable for this case - send the application to background and then bring it up again.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I wanted to background the app and open it where I previously left it. To background the app:

```swift
XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
```

To re-open the app where I left it:

```swift
XCUIApplication().activate()
```

Re-launching the app using `XCUIApplication().launch()` would launch the app from new.

*I am using Swift 4.2*

Answer (score 6):

I just tried `UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector("suspend")` successfully.

```
dispatch_after(2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {       
    // suspend the app after two seconds
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector("suspend")
})

// Swift 4 version
UIApplication.shared.perform(Selector("suspend"))
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work for XCode Automated UI Tests, should this work? Or is this answer appropriate for another type of testing?

Comment: @tilo It doesn't work for me (Xcode 7.3.1).

    dispatch_after(2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // suspend the app after two seconds
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector(#selector(NSURLSessionTask.suspend))
    })

Does it simply put the app into suspend state, instead of background state?

Comment: @Liam Have you found the way to do this in UITest? I still finding on this, but no clue :(

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 9.0, Apple introduced [`XCUIApplication.activate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2873317-activate). `activate()` will launch the application if necessary, but will not terminate it if it is already running. Thus:

```
func testExample() {
    // Background the app
    XCUIDevice().press(.home)
    // Reactivate the app
    XCUIApplication().activate()
}
```