# how to unit test uploading happens when the app is running in the background

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I want to write a unit test function, which aims at testing uploading happens when the app is running in the background. It is generally like this:

```
func checkBackgroundUploading() {
   set the UIState to be background
   write a record and upload it to database in this UIState
}
```

I know how to do the second step, but how to set the UIState to be background?

Answer (score 1):

I have had success in testing sounds in the background by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652978/programmatically-sending-an-app-to-background), that I found on SO. 
The gist of it is to send the app to the background by programmatically pressing the home button. Hope it helps.

```
    XCUIDevice().pressButton(XCUIDeviceButton.Home)
```