# On Button click, I want to bring app to background from fore ground?Is it possible? and How?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10, background-mode

When I click the button, I want my app which is running in foreground needs to go to background. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652978/programmatically-sending-an-app-to-background

Comment: Found already, But it is not woking...

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: This is an private instance method. Your app may get rejected in the app store.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];
```

Comment: what do we write inside suspend method to bring app to background from foreground?

Answer (score 0):

@IBAction func bringToBackgroundButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)

{

let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

app.performSelector(#selector(self.suspend))

}

func suspend()
{

exit(0)

}

makes your app which is running in foreground will go to background.

This is not recommended, not sure about app store approval.