# UI-Test with XCTest: how to trigger App-State Foreground-Inactive Foreground-Active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

How can I trigger the following behavior in Swift UI Tests via **XCTest**:

Get the app to *foreground and inactive* (`applicationWillResignActive`) and back to *"foreground and active"* (`applicationDidBecomeActive`)

Possible gestures, while app is in foreground and active, could be:

- open app switcher and go back to app
- open control center and hide control center
- open notification center and hide notification center

I searched for something like that following *fictive(!) code* `XCUIDevice.shared.doublePress(XCUIDevice.Button.home)` or `XCUIDevice.shared.swipeDownFromOutside(); XCUIDevice.shared.swipeUpFromOutside()`.

Or a more better way a method call to simulate an open app switcher, control center or notification center immediately.

Or in the best way to simulate the status `applicationWillResignActive`, `applicationDidBecomeActive` immediately.

Important to understand: the event `applicationDidEnterBackground` must not called - the app has to stay in foreground (but inactive)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically sending an app to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652978/programmatically-sending-an-app-to-background)

Answer (score 0):

So recently on wwdc2017 Apple released a convenient way to work with multi app. You can see the multi App portion of the video link below.

```
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409/
```

Comment: The link is now broken.